# Cells sized independently of rows MigLayout

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, miglayout

[image: Poorly rendered graphical representation of the picture in my head]

So I am designing a rather simple layout for an item manager program which i am making in Java with Swing.

Typically, the cells light colored row would all stretch down to meet the blue. However, I am curious to know if you can enable cells to be sized independently of their rows.

Any ideas would be most appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, it's possible. Use `unrel` as a row height constraint. See the [cheat sheet](http://migcalendar.com/miglayout/cheatsheet.html) for more details. However, I'd really advise a separate `JPanel` per column, for simplicity reasons. You can use `insets 0` as a layout constraint here if you don't like the insets.

Comment: For some reason I lost sight of all the panels I had added to this layout. I don't have the rep to upvote this, otherwise i would. I will leave it unchecked for a bit to see if anyone has anything else to add

Comment: Im going with the independent `JPanels`

Comment: I have a similar configuration -- there's a list box where you can select the view for each column, and then the JPanel is loaded dynamically depending on the user choice. The contents are sized per column.

Comment: @ChrisDennett, Any chance i could have a peek at your source code?